# Mathematica 13.0 simplifies trigonometric integral wrong

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I calculate the following general expression:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[2/L*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L+\[Phi]1]*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L+\[Phi]2]*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*qt*x)/L+\[Phi]3],{x,0,L}],Element[q|qt,Integers]]
```

and I get:

```
0
```

This is wrong in general because of the following special case. For qt = 2q:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[2/L*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L+\[Phi]1]*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L+\[Phi]2]*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*qt*x)/L+\[Phi]3]/.{qt->2*q},{x,0,L}],Element[q|qt,Integers]]
```

I get the sine of some phases:

```
1/2 Sin[\[Phi]1+\[Phi]2-\[Phi]3]
```

I have confirmed the special case with pen and paper. Can somebody please tell me why Mathematica screws the general case up like this? It is a plain old mistake by the most sophisticated symbolic maths engine on the planet. Or...?

Comment: Please add cross-links to-from the corresponding Wolfram Community post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not too uncommon for `Integrate` to return something which has a special case that can't be evaluated properly without taking a limit.  In your case there is a denominator equal to `0` when `qt == 2q`, but you get the correct formula from `Limit[yourIntegral, qt -> 2 q]`.

When `FullSimplify` sees the denominator it concludes `qt != 2q` which makes the expression `0`.

Comment: Why not return a conditional such as "0 if qt != 2q"? Then the user could check the special case themselves. That would make mathematica much more useful for mathematicians... (I am actually used to correct conditionals returned by Mathematica. I don't expect Mathematica to make mistakes like this.)

Comment: That is great, but `ClearAll[q,qt,L,\[Phi]1 ,\[Phi]2 ,\[Phi]3 ];Integrate[  2/L*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L + \[Phi]1]*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L + \[Phi]2]*   Sin[(2*\[Pi]*qt*x)/L + \[Phi]3], {x, 0, L},   Assumptions -> {q, qt} \[Element] Integers &&     L > 0 && \[Phi]1 > 0 && \[Phi]3 > 0 && \[Phi]2 > 0,   GenerateConditions -> True]`  on a fresh kernel returns a long expression.

Comment: @dimitsev `FunctionSingularities[res, {q, qt}]` returns the conditions you seek. The issue is, as Coolwater pointed out, is the simplification functions make transformations that are generically true. FWIW, this handles one of the singularities: `res /. Sin[z_] :> z*Sinc[z] // Simplify`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to eliminate the singularities in the answer, provided you can be happy removing a singularity of the form `Sin[u]/u` with `Sinc[u]`.  We end up with a very nice simplification.

There are three singularities, which may be found by inspection or by computing

```
FunctionSingularities[res, {q, qt, ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3}]
(*  qt == 0 || 4 q^2 - qt^2 == 0  *)
```

The singularities at `u == 2 q - qt` and `u == 2 u + qt` are more easily dealt with via substitutions:

```
qt ->  2 q + u
qt -> -2 q + u
```

The basic idea is to expand the result into a sum of terms that have `1/u` and terms that do not.  This is possible in the OP's result but obviously not in general.  You have to check this.  Since in the OP's case the singularity at `1/u` is removable, we apply the sinc identity on the terms with `1/u`.  The case where `u = qt` has a particularly simple solution that does not require separating the terms. The other two use `Cases[]` to separate the terms.

```
res = FullSimplify@ Integrate[
   2/L*Sin[(2*π*q*x)/L + ϕ1]*Sin[(2*π*q*x)/L + ϕ2]*
    Sin[(2*π*qt*x)/L + ϕ3], {x, 0, L}];
singqt = res /. Sin[z : Pi qt] :> z*Sinc[z] // Simplify;
singminus = singqt /. qt -> 2 q + u // Simplify // TrigExpand;
singminus = Simplify[
     Total@ Cases[singminus, t_ /; ! FreeQ[t, 1/u]] /.
      {1/u -> Pi*Sinc[Pi u]/Sin[Pi u]}
     ] + Total@ Cases[singminus, t_ /; FreeQ[t, 1/u]] /. u -> qt - 2 q;
singplus = singminus /. qt -> -2 q + u // Simplify // TrigExpand;
singplus = Simplify[
     Total@ Cases[singplus, t_ /; ! FreeQ[t, 1/u]] /.
      {1/u -> Pi*Sinc[Pi u]/Sin[Pi u]}
     ] + Total@ Cases[singplus, t_ /; FreeQ[t, 1/u]] /. u -> qt + 2 q;
integral = singplus // FullSimplify
(*
  1/2 (2 Cos[ϕ1 - ϕ2] Sin[π qt + ϕ3] Sinc[π qt] +
    Sin[2 π q - π qt + ϕ1 + ϕ2 - ϕ3] Sinc[π (-2 q + qt)] -
    Sin[2 π q + π qt + ϕ1 + ϕ2 + ϕ3] Sinc[π (2 q + qt)])
*)
```

Check:

```
res - integral // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify
(*  0  *)
```

Since `integral` is continuous, it makes sense that there are no conditions on the result `res` from an integration point of view. That `res` has removable singularities may seem unfortunate to some, but others sometimes wish Mathematica would stick to elementary functions when it can.

*Update*

I should have taken it one more step:

```
FullSimplify[integral, {q, qt} ∈ Integers]
(*
  ((-1)^qt *
    (KroneckerDelta[qt] 2 Cos[ϕ1 - ϕ2] Sin[ϕ3] + 
     KroneckerDelta[2*q - qt] Sin[ϕ1 + ϕ2 - ϕ3] -  
     KroneckerDelta[2 q + qt] Sin[ϕ1 + ϕ2 + ϕ3]))/2
*)
```

*Update 2*

Here's a simplified way to get the simplified `integral`, which can then be simplified further to get `KroneckerDelta[]` as above:

```
integral = res // Apart[#, q] & //
  Map[# /. Sin[Pi z_] :> Pi z Sinc[Pi z] &]
```

Answer (score 2):

Under natural assumptions one obtains

```
Integrate[2/L*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L + \[Phi]1]*
Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L + \[Phi]2]*
Sin[(2*\[Pi]*qt*x)/L + \[Phi]3], {x, 0, L}, 
Assumptions -> {q, qt} \[Element] Integers && 
L > 0 && \[Phi]1 > 0 && \[Phi]3 > 0 && \[Phi]2 > 0, 
GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `((-4 q^2 + qt^2) Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] -  qt (2 q + qt) Cos[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] +  2 q qt Cos[4 \[Pi] q - 2 \[Pi] qt + \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] +  qt^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] q - 2 \[Pi] qt + \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] -  4 q^2 Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] +  qt^2 Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] +  4 q^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] qt + \[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] -  qt^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] qt + \[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] +  4 q^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] qt - \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] -  qt^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] qt - \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] +  2 q qt Cos[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] -  qt^2 Cos[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] -  2 q qt Cos[4 \[Pi] q + 2 \[Pi] qt + \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] +  qt^2 Cos[ 4 \[Pi] q +  2 \[Pi] qt + \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3])/(4 \[Pi] qt (-4 q^2 + qt^2))`

```
Limit[%, qt -> 0]
```

> `((4 \[Pi] q Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2] + Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2] -  Sin[4 \[Pi] q + \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2]) Sin[\[Phi]3])/(4 \[Pi] q)`

```
Limit[%%, qt -> 2 q]
```

> `(1/(16 \[Pi] q))(2 Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] +  2 Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] -  2 Cos[4 \[Pi] q + \[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] -  2 Cos[4 \[Pi] q - \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] -  Cos[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] +  Cos[8 \[Pi] q + \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] +  8 \[Pi] q Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3])`

```
Limit[%%%, qt -> -2 q]
```

> `-(1/(16 \[Pi] q))(2 Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] -  2 Cos[4 \[Pi] q + \[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] -  2 Cos[4 \[Pi] q - \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] -  Cos[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] +  Cos[8 \[Pi] q + \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] +  2 Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] +  8 \[Pi] q Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3])`

Addition.

```
FullSimplify[-(1/(16 \[Pi] q)) (2 Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] - 
2 Cos[4 \[Pi] q + \[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] - 
2 Cos[4 \[Pi] q - \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] - 
Cos[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] + 
Cos[8 \[Pi] q + \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 - \[Phi]3] + 
2 Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3] + 
8 \[Pi] q Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3]), 
 Assumptions -> {q, qt} \[Element] Integers]
```

> `-(1/2) Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2 + \[Phi]3]`

Comment: The same is obtained only with `Integrate[
 2/L*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L + \[Phi]1]*Sin[(2*\[Pi]*q*x)/L + \[Phi]2]*
  Sin[(2*\[Pi]*qt*x)/L + \[Phi]3], {x, 0, L}, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]`.

Comment: It is clear without firing a cannon at sparrows the only possible singularities are at the zeroes of the denominator `(4 \[Pi] qt (-4 q^2 + qt^2))`.